# How to Pass output of one query as input to another query using SQL

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

Really appreciate if I can get any help on this

I have one sql query i.e query1 which displays the list of users who are not logged in to our application and another query "query2" that uses the ouput of query 1 and disables those user. Until now I had to manually run the two query individually, but now I have to automate the process.

My question is how can I pass the output of query1 as input to query2 without any manually work. I did some research and found out that this can be done using procedures and I need to create cursors as well. If this is true please let me know the steps on how to proceed further

I have Oracle database on the backend for our application. and we use SQL to retrieve the data

Thanks 
victor

Comment: How exactly do you "disable" the user? An update statement maybe? Please post both queries

Comment: You can do that using stored procedure but it might not be necessary for you. This problem could be solved by using sub-queries, just try it...

Comment: In your post, you say you have *Oracle database* - yet the tag reads `sql-server` (that is: Microsoft SQL Server) - so which is it now??

Comment: we have oracle DB and we use sql to retrieve the data.

Comment: yes query2 is an update query but im unable to post it.since im new to this site please let me knw how do i post both my queries as they are quite huge about 700 lines

Answer (score 4):

I'm not an Oracle guy, but this should work:

```
update tbl1
set IsEnabled = 1
where UserId in (select UserId from tbl2 where IsLoggedIn = 0)
```

Comment: Works also on MS SQL Server. Validated both on 2014 and 2016. Thanks!

Comment: @bizna - I said "I'm not an Oracle guy", but I most definitely *am* a SQL Server guy. :)